Bad Gateway error when trying to list documents in an iManage workspace with iManage REST API Version 2
I'm trying to use the iManage REST API Version 2 to list all the documents in an iManage Workspace. This is how far I got:
Based on an iManage matter number XXXXXX.NNNN I can get the workspaces:
https://imanage.[ourclient].[etc]/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/[theirdatabase]/workspaces/search?limit=1000&offset=0&total=true&custom1=XXXXXX&custom2=NNNN

This returns at least one workspace . These are some of its relevant settings:
content_type: P
database: (this matches the value I passed in the previous REST api)
default_security: public
the workspace_id looks like DBNAME!NUMBER

Please let me know if you need any more settings; I can provide as needed as long as they're not identifying features for the actual database we're connecting to...
After that we try to call the REST API to list the documents in this workspace
https://imanage.[ourclient].[etc]/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/[theirdatabase]/documents/search?total=true&limit=9999&offset=0&scope=DBNAME!NUMBER

It appears that this call is timing out. After a LONG wait it fails with 502 Bad Gateway
Storing the URL in a variable named sURL this is the code I am trying to use to perform this request
request = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sURL), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", [token retrieved during login])
request.Method = "GET"

The error occurs on
response = DirectCast(request.GetResponseAsync().Result, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)

This seemed to work fine when the code was written, now quite a while ago. We already had to give up on integrating our software with one client because of this error. On that occasion the call would sometimes succeed and sometimes fail. Even when trying the exact same call a number of times in a row, it would sometimes succeed and sometimes fail, which leads me to think that we may be at the receiving end of a "timeout" of some description. In the case of the current client, however, this call persistently fails every single time.
Am I missing something?
